# How to add empty space bottom of LazyColumn?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

i want to add empty space bottom of LazyColumn, and I want to allow the user to bring up the bottom element. How can i archieve this.

Example;

```
LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(300.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Red),
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(25.dp)
                ){
                    items(7) {
                        Surface(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .height(100.dp),
                            color = Color.Gray
                        ) {}
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                    }
                }
```

I want to increase the length of a

[image]

Note: I want to be able to scroll up even when I come to the last element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try Spacer outside the items block -

`item { Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(100.dp)) }`

Comment: this solution is just adding padding outside of lazycolumn. I want to be able to scroll up even when I come to the last element.

Comment: I already have spacer in my code, when I add space like this it adds space under each element. I just want to add below.

Comment: Try this outside the items block - 
LazyColumn(
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(300.dp).border(2.dp, Color.Red),
contentPadding = PaddingValues(25.dp)
){
    items(7) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(100.dp),
            color = Color.Gray
        ) {}
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
    }
    item { Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(100.dp)) }
}

Comment: They’re saying to add it as a separate item, not in the items block.

Answer (score 0):

its simple man, just add a simple if to check is the item is the last example :

```
LazyColumn (Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    items(desiredItemList) { itemList ->
            // add whatever component u have
            if (itemList == desiredItemList.last()) Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(84.dp))
    }
}
```

in your case it'll be

```
if (it == 7) Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
```